# Why does the output of the function 0 even though 0 isn't in the range?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am a python developer learning javascript and NODE.js. I was practicing some javascript and one of the things I miss in python is the random.randint() function. I have tried to code my own randint function using Math.random(). The function is working great but the problem is that sometimes it outputs a value that isn't within the range given.

```
function true_round(num){

    if (Number.isInteger(num)) { return num; }

    let [before, after] = String(num).split(".");

    if (Number(after.slice(0, 1)) >= 5) { return Number(before) + 1; }

    else { return Number(before); }

}


function randint(lowerbound, upperbound){

    if (upperbound > 0){ 

        let rand = lowerbound + true_round(upperbound * Math.random());

        if (rand > upperbound){ return upperbound; }

        return rand;

    }

    else if (upperbound <= 0){

        let rand = upperbound + true_round(lowerbound * Math.random())

        if (rand < lowerbound){ return lowerbound; }

        return rand;

    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++){ console.log(randint(-2, -1)); }
```

I expect all the outputs to be within the range given but it gives me 0 sometimes.

Comment: The problem is in your `true_round` function. You should round to the preceding integer and not the following, if it is negative and the first digit is >= 5. With your code, `true_round(-1.6) === 0`

Comment: On a side note, you basically rewrote [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round). Also see the [getRandomInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values) implementation by Mozilla which is quite simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your true_round function.

Try true_round(-1.9) and you'll get 0. This is because in your round up case you always adds 1, even though in the case of -1.9 you need to *subtract* 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your `true_round()` has issues with rounding negative Numbers.
See here: [image: REPL test].

Because when its -0.6, your Programm will say `0 + 1` because its higher than 5 right?
To fix this you can either use `Math.round()` or instead of adding 1, make a check if its a negative number and then subtract one.

Also if you want some great and short examples for random Numbers in a range have a look at MDN great examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random ( eg.: [`getRandomIntInclusive(min, max)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values_inclusive) [`getRandomInt(min, max)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values) )